# Работа с объектами в JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как создать свойство объекта, в имя которого входит переменная?
Например:

```
 test={test: 'text'}
```

Но здесь надо создать ещё одно свойство в зависимости от значения переменной

```
test.значение = ещё одно значение;
```

Как такое осуществить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var obj = {}, 
    name = 'test';
obj[name] = true;
alert(obj[name]); // true
```

[Пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/frygm/)